# SSH.net crushed when called to run remote opencv program

Tags: c#, opencv, ssh, ssh.net

I have a opencv program as a server to send image stream from camera. Now I have to make a c# program to open the opencv program remotely.

everything is good by using ssh via cmd.
like:

```
ssh myname@ip
export DISPLAY=":0"
~/home/MyName/MyOpencvProgram
```

and I can see a imshow windows pop-up in my server computer.

Now I want to make this in c# WPF program so I use SSH.NET package:

```
public void TrySomeSSh()
        {
            ConnectionInfo conInfo = new ConnectionInfo(ip, _port, _username, new AuthenticationMethod[]{
    new PasswordAuthenticationMethod(_username,_password)});
            SshClient sshClient = new SshClient(conInfo);
            sshClient.Connect();
            if (sshClient.IsConnected)
            {
                SshCommand output1;
                string line1 = "export DISPLAY=\":0\"";
                output1 = sshClient.RunCommand(line1);
                Console.WriteLine(output1.Execute());
                Console.WriteLine(line1);
                string line = "/home/MyName/MyOpencvProgram";
                Console.WriteLine(line);
                var output2 = sshClient.RunCommand(line);
                Console.WriteLine(output2.Execute());
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("not connected");
            }
            sshClient.Disconnect();
            sshClient.Dispose();
        }
```

from the output.Execute() I can see the program is running. However it would always stop when meet some GUI function like **namedwindow()** , **imshow()** , or **waitKey()** .All of these work fine when use ssh via cmd, and I think the export DISPLAY=":0" command is enough to solve this. But It still stopped.

What should I do now?

Comment: See [Run and execute multiple dependent SSH commands using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56434268/850848).

Answer (score 0):

thanks Prikryl's comment, as the link says each RunCommand() function runs in their own shell ,RunCommand() would not remember the variable we give. So we have to put the command together

like:

```
public void TrySomeSSh()
        {
            ConnectionInfo conInfo = new ConnectionInfo(ip, _port, _username, new AuthenticationMethod[]{
    new PasswordAuthenticationMethod(_username,_password)});
            SshClient sshClient = new SshClient(conInfo);
            sshClient.Connect();
            if (sshClient.IsConnected)
            {
                SshCommand output1;
                 output1 = sshClient.RunCommand("export DISPLAY=\"127.0.0.1:10.0\" ; /home/MyName/MyOpencvProgram ");
              Console.WriteLine(output1.CommandText);
              Console.WriteLine(output1.Execute());

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("not connected");
            }
            sshClient.Disconnect();
            sshClient.Dispose();
        }
```